# image not stretched on mobile devices caused horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a webpage as linked:

[Click Here](http://iloveword.com/website/instructions/)

Everything is fine on PC or MAC.  The issue is if you look at it on a mobile devices, you will find that the 3 images caused a horizontal scroll bar.

I use this to set the viewport for mobile device consideration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=320, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I use a sprite method to set the div background, for showing the 3 images.

HTML:

```
<div class="demopic" id="category"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.demopic {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px auto;
      background: url(http://7te8e7.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/sprite_instructions.png);
    }

#category {
      width: 560px;
      height: 590px;
    }
```

My question is, based on my situation, is there a quick fix to achieve a responsive image?  I don't want to show the horizontal scroll bar on mobile devices.

If I delete `initial-scale=1.0` in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=320, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`, the image will be compressed for a proper size, but at the same time, the font-size will be resized as well.

Anyone give me some inspiration will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're best bet is to use the standard img tag and make sure the image never expands wider than it's parent container (could just be the body element).

```
.my-image {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

This should do the trick.

However, if you really want to use the div / background image approach things are slightly more complex.

```
.my-background-image {
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    background:url(img.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Here we set an element to fill it's parents width. Then we make it's height proportional to it's width using padding-bottom (you'll need to tweak this). Finally we make the background size always fill the element. Worth noting that background size won't work in IE8.